# Undefined (reading 'web') error when using pnp/sp

Tags: spfx-webparts, pnpjs

I am trying to write a web part that gives the user a list of document libraries for the current site they are in, allows them to choose from this list, and then click a button which then gets all of the items in the relative folder of each of the choices, and exports it to Excel.   The first function getCheckBoxes works fine, but when I click the Button, I get the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'web')
```

I have tried a few different ways of doing this, and tried using the this.state to store the choices (which are currently being stored in the choices array) but nothing works.

so the first this._sp.web.lists.... line in getCheckBoxes works fine.  But the one in _processData doesn't.

Hope that makes sense.  Some of the interfaces are not being used so it might be a bit messy.

Full code is:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Checkbox, getAriaDescribedBy, Label, PrimaryButton, Stack } from '@fluentui/react';
import "@pnp/sp/webs/index.js"
import "@pnp/sp/items/index.js";
import "@pnp/sp/folders/index.js";
import "@pnp/sp/lists/index.js";
import "@pnp/sp/sites/index.js";
import { IFile, IFolder, IResponseItem } from "./interfaces";
import { WebPartContext} from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { SPFI, spfi } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
import { getSP } from "../../../pnpjs-presets";
import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

export interface WebPartProps {
  context: WebPartContext;
  description: string;
}
export interface PageContextInfo{
 url?:string
}
export interface IAsyncAwaitPnPJsProps {
  description: string;
}
export interface MYListProperties {      
  BaseName: string;    
  Modified :String;
  ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl :string;
  Editor: Array<string>;
  FileRef: string;    
}    
const fileType = 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=UTF-8';  
const fileExtension = '.xlsx';  
var Heading = [  ["Name","ModifiedBy", "Modified Date", "Folder", "URL",],];  
const saveExcel = (ListData) => {  
  if(ListData.length>0)  
  {  
  const ws = XLSX.utils.book_new();  
   // const ws = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(csvData,{header:["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"], skipHeader:false});  
   XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(ws, Heading);  
   XLSX.utils.sheet_add_json(ws, ListData, { origin: 'A2', skipHeader: true });         
    const wb = { Sheets: { 'data': ws }, SheetNames: ['data'] };  
    const excelBuffer = XLSX.write(wb, { bookType: 'xlsx', type: 'array' });  
    const data = new Blob([excelBuffer], {type: fileType});  
    saveAs(data, 'Data' + fileExtension);  
  }  
} ;
export interface IExportToExcelProps {
  items: IFile[];
}
export interface ICFolder{
  Title:string;
}
export interface ICheckboxStates
{
  items:IFile[];
}
var multivaluechoices:IFolder[] = [];
let choices: ICFolder[] = [];


export default class ExportDocLibToExcel extends React.Component<IExportToExcelProps, ICheckboxStates> {
  public _sp: SPFI;

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this._sp = getSP();
  }
  public async componentDidMount(){
    this.getCheckBoxes();
  }


public async getCheckBoxes(){

  await this._sp.web.lists.filter('BaseTemplate eq 101')().then((fields) => {

    console.log(fields);
    for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
      multivaluechoices.push({
        Title: fields[i].Title
      });
    }

  });
}


public async _processData(){

  for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++){
    let LIBRARY_NAME = choices[i].Title;
    console.log(choices[i].Title);
    await this._sp.web.lists.getByTitle(LIBRARY_NAME).items
       .select("BaseName, ID, Modified, Editor/Title, FSObjType, FileLeafRef, FileRef, ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl")
       .filter("FSObjType eq 0")
       .expand("Editor")().then((response) => {   
       
   console.log(response);     
   });
   }; 
};


  public render(): React.ReactElement<IAsyncAwaitPnPJsProps> {
    return (
      <div>
<PrimaryButton text="Export to Excel" onClick={this._processData} allowDisabledFocus />
    
        {multivaluechoices.map((item) => {
          return (
              <div style={{margin:"2px",padding:"3px"}}>    
                  <Checkbox label={item.Title}  title={item.Title} ariaLabel={item.Title} onChange={_onChange}/>
              </div>            
          );
        })}
    </div>

    );
  }

}

function _onChange(ev?: React.FormEvent<HTMLElement | HTMLInputElement>, isChecked?:boolean) {
const target = ev.target as HTMLInputElement;
if(target.checked == true){
  choices.push({
Title: target.title
  })
}
}
```

EDIT : So I have now added the Caching option:

```
public async _processData(){


  const spCache = spfi(this._sp).using(Caching(cacheProps));

  for(var i = 0; i < choices.length; i++){
    let LIBRARY_NAME = choices[i].Title;
    console.log(choices[i].Title);
    await spCache.web.lists.getByTitle(LIBRARY_NAME).items
       .select("BaseName, ID, Modified, Editor/Title, FSObjType, FileLeafRef, FileRef, ServerRedirectedEmbedUrl")
       .filter("FSObjType eq 0")
       .expand("Editor")().then((response) => {  
       
   console.log(response);     
   });
   }; 
};
```

However, I am now getting the error

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unhandled Exception: TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL
```

and that error is occuring in the timeline.js file.

Comment: Try adding this inside the constructor: `this._processData = this._processData.bind(this);`. Let me know if this works.

Comment: It didn't work.  Back to the undefined 'web' error again.  Have tried it multiple ways.  I think I'm going to rebuild by project from scratch just incase I have done something wrong while installing the plugins for imports.  Thank you.